# Installing WebAudio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

When looking into tutorials and resources for WebAudio Api there is never a mention of what files I should have in my directories to run it. I'm using WebStrom hoping to use it with javascript I am working on, and the functions mentioned in any of the tutorials always are unresolved as there are no files for them to reference. Where can I find the files for WebAudio Api?

Comment: Are you asking how to get Webstorm to provide syntax highlighting & autocomplete? Or are you asking what files you need to use the WebAudio API in a browser because you don't need any, the browser either supports it (Chrome/Firefox) or it doesn't (IE)

Comment: You might want to install JavaScript first, as it's a dependency for Web Audio: http://vanilla-js.com

Comment: @RGraham Thank you for answering. Both, but since now I understand there are no outstanding files I'm missing I still am curious how I might bring WebStrom to not see the lack of those functions as an error. This might be best opened in another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebAudio api is not something you install. It is buil-in your browser. You can access it from your javascript without installing anything. But be careful to check its availability in older browsers still in use.

Take a look here for compatibility http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api